# How commonly known is Spider-man's origin?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

In *Avengers: The Initiative #1*, Gyrich remarks of superhero origins:

[image: Gyrich in Avengers: The Initiative. "... spider bites. The way God intended"]

How widely known was the origin of Spider-man (at this point - between *Civil War* and *Secret Invasion*) in the 616 universe?

I don't recall the origin being announced during the unmasking in *Civil War #2/3* and *Amazing Spider-man #533*.

Did the events of *One More Day* affect this knowledge along with Spider-man's secret identity?

Comment: Could this just be a throwaway _[4th wall](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fourth+Wall)_ sort of comment?

Comment: That's certainly a possibility.

Comment: Gyrich has access to a lot of information that the public doesn't have, having been a liason for the Avengers, a part of Project Wideawake, and a member of the Commission for Superhero Activities. Additionally, while I don't recall Peter revealing that fact during the initial press conference, the media really started digging afterwards, and it's possible/likely that that bit of information was released afterwards.